# Permissions Elevation for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, uac, sudo, elevated-privileges

Ive got a java app which needs to execute a driver installer exe file.  On Linux we type "gksudo myCommand".    Is there a way to elevate permissions from Windows command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to deploy an executable binary onto the system which calls the jar.  This way the user can right click and run as administrator...  That didn't work... SO I kept looking...  Check this out..

Elevate.exe..  It's basically like Windows GKSudo!!!!
http://www.robotronic.de/elevate.html

So... I packaged the 32bit exe into my program and deploy it, then run it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may run every application in windows with a different user e.g. Administrator. But the user who executes this command needs to have the credentials to do so.

Edit.:

In advance you can lookup the User Account Control (UAC) which is available in Windows 7 and Vista if it is possibly an alternative for you.

Comment: what about the UAC popup that says something like... this app is requesting permissions...  How do I invoke that?

Comment: There must be a better way....  I could always request that the user type their password with runas /user:administrator /savecred my command... then just pipe their answer into my stdin

Comment: The thing is you are doing the same things in linux aswell gksudo or plain sudo is nothing else than running a command as different user with superuser rights(in the case of linux as root). I edited my post and added the UAC to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runas` command like `runas /user:Administrator myCommand` (it requires the users to type password).

You can also use `Start-Process` cmdlet like `Start-Process -Verb runas myCommand` in PowerShell (it requires the users to click the UAC dialog).

see: http://satob.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/06/17/013217